# Survival analysis with two different observation periods

Tags: time-series, survival

Can you use survival analysis to find the time to event across different tasks or observation periods (where the end of the observation period varies)?

Comment: It's a common practice to left align entities with differing observations periods. You lose the actual time signature in the data but gain the ability for direct comparison. Censoring remains the same.

Comment: @MikeHunter thank you for responding! Does this mean I will not be able to compare the time to event across the two observation periods? If so, what would I be predicting?

Comment: Of course you can compare the time to event. Left alignment preserves the unit of time. So, if the unit of time is expressed as a date, then left alignment just shifts from actual date (e.g., Jan 1, Jan 2, etc.) to days (1, 2, 3, etc.). Thus making a comparison of time to failure possible.

Comment: @MikeHunter I see, would this also be the case with smaller time units like seconds?

Comment: Seconds nested with minutes nested within hours nested within days, yes.